# Magento 2 Custom Module and Webservice returns blank array

Tags: php, xml, web-services, magento, magento2

I am a newbie to magento 2x. However I tried to create a custom module and a webservice to check a customer email is exist or not. But as a result I am getting just a blank array. Here is what I have done so far:

**1. app/code/Test/Customers/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Test_Customers',
        __DIR__
    );
```

**2. app/code/Test/Customers/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"><module name="Test_Customers" setup_version="1.0.0"></module></config>
```

**3. app/code/Test/Customers/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"><preference for="Test\Customers\Api\AccountInterface" type="Test\Customers\Model\Account"/></config>
```

**4. app/code/Test/Customers/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd"><route url="/V1/customers/isEmailExist/" method="POST"><service class="Test\Customers\Api\AccountInterface" method="isEmailExist"/><resources><resource ref="anonymous"/></resources></route></routes>
```

**5. app/code/Test/Customers/Api/AccountInterface.php**

```
    namespace Test\Customers\Api;
/**
 * Account interface.
 * @api
 */

interface AccountInterface
{
    /**
     * Check if given email is associated with a customer account in given website.
     * @api
     * @param string $customerEmail
     * @return \Test\Customers\Api\AccountInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function isEmailExist($customerEmail);
}
```

**6. app/code/Test/Customers/Model/Account.php**

```
namespace Test\Customers\Model;

use Test\Customers\Api\AccountInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

    class Account implements AccountInterface
    {

        /**
         * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $customerRepository;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory */
        protected $resultJsonFactory;

        /**
         * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
        {
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public
        function isEmailExist($customerEmail)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory */
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            try {
                $this->customerRepository->get($customerEmail);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

            }

            return $result->setData(['success' => true]);

        }
      }
```

I tried a POST request from REST client

http://127.0.0.1/PATH_TO_MAGENTO_DIRECTORY/index.php/rest/V1/customers/isEmailExist

POST Body:

```
{
    "customerEmail": "sa@example.com"
}
```

and got a [] as response

Comment: Debug your functionalit is called and you get all parameter info in your function.

Comment: @Jammer I get the same issue did you find what was missing?